# Animate Text bpy.ops.transform.translate

Tags: animation, scripting, text-object, bezier-curves

I am trying to find the right code to animate text that follows a bezier curve in python blender api. I can add the keyframes, and they appear to be working when I drag through the timeline, but when I run script it sets just one keyframe. I need to be able to tell it the start keyframe at frame 1 and the end keyframe at frame 249. Here is part of the code I am using:

```
bpy.context.object.name = "Text"

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CURVE')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Curve"].object = bpy.data.objects["Circle.Text"]

bpy.context.object.modifiers["Curve"].deform_axis = 'NEG_X'

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, axis=(1, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, snap=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', snap_point=(0, 0, 0), snap_align=False, snap_normal=(0, 0, 0), release_confirm=False)


bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(12.8872, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, snap=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', snap_point=(0, 0, 0), snap_align=False, snap_normal=(0, 0, 0), texture_space=False, release_confirm=True)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location', confirm_success=False, always_prompt=False)


bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-11.6886, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, snap=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', snap_point=(0, 0, 0), snap_align=False, snap_normal=(0, 0, 0), texture_space=False, release_confirm=True)
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location', confirm_success=False, always_prompt=False)
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

**Ditch the operators**

[image]
*Test run with default text and default bezier circle objects*

Below is code which does, what I believe to be, same as above, but without any operators.  For case of example I have used an object named "Text" in scene for text object, and an object named "BezierCircle" for the curve. *Change to suit*

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from math import radians

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

text = scene.objects.get("Text")
curve = scene.objects.get("BezierCircle")

if text and curve:
    # add modifier
    cm = text.modifiers.new("foo", 'CURVE')
    cm.object = curve
    cm.deform_axis = 'NEG_X'
    # rotate 
    R = Matrix.Rotation(radians(90), 4, 'X')
    text.matrix_world @= R # replace @ with * for pre 2.8
    # translation
    text.matrix_world.translation += Vector((12.8872, 0, 0))
    # insert keyframe
    text.keyframe_insert("location", frame=1)
    # and again
    text.matrix_world.translation += Vector((-11.6886, 0, 0))
    text.keyframe_insert("location", frame=249)
```